# How do I access structure elements in called function?

Tags: function, struct, scilab

I have a structure with two fields and I am passing this structure to a function in scilab.
How to access elements of this structure in the called function?

```
%Scilab console
S=struct('day',30,'month','may');
fun(S);

%called function
function fun(element)
    fields=fieldnames(element);
    disp(element.fields(1));
    disp(element.fields(2));
endfunction;
```

I tried bit differently,like

```
disp(element.(fields(1)));
disp(element.(fields(2)));
```

and changed '()' to '{}' and '[]',but none of them given me the output I required

Is there any way to do this?

thanks in advance =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Accessing all elements without knowing number of fields or field names

Using [`getfield`](https://help.scilab.org/docs/5.5.2/en_US/getfield.html) you can extract fields by name. If you iterate through all fieldnames returned by [`fieldnames`](https://help.scilab.org/docs/5.5.2/en_US/fieldnames.html) you can get all fields. See example below.

```
function fun(element)
    fields=fieldnames(element);
    for i=1:length(fields(1,:))-1
        fieldname = fields(i)
        fielddata = getfield(fields(i), element)

        printf('%s: %s\n', string(fieldname), string(fielddata))
    end
endfunction;
```

### Accessing fields if you know the field names

If you know the fieldnames of a struct you can simply call them directly.

```
function fun2(date_struct)
       printf('day: %s\n', string(date_struct.day))
       printf('month: %s\n', string(date_struct.month)) 
endfunction
```